# Проблема с получением url запроса nodejs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios

Доброго всем времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю запрос на сервер nodejs:

```
axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001',
    }).then(res => setProduct(res));
```

Путь с которого делаю запрос `http://localhost:5173/products/64da0c31487da0f07aed6fa0`

В обработке запроса

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        goodsRequest(res, req.url);
    }
});
```

`req.url == '/'` получаю такой путь, хотя по идеи должен получать `/products/64da0c31487da0f07aed6fa0`
Подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: С чего это вот из этого `url: 'http://localhost:3001'` должно как то получиться это `/products/64da0c31487da0f07aed6fa0`? Вы же обращаетесь на ноду по адресу http://localhost:3001

Answer (score 0):

Я создал такой сервер...

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url)
    res.end('Тест');
});
server.listen(5173);
```

Запустил браузер и в адресной строке вставил твой УРЛ `http://localhost:5173/products/64da0c31487da0f07aed6fa0` - в консоли сервера увидел `/products/64da0c31487da0f07aed6fa0`...

Т.ч. ты что-то от нас скрываешь.